# Razor Safe Check InvalidExpressionTerm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to render a Razor view in a web application. It is failing miserably on this line:

```
if (Model?.Items == null)
{
    return;
}
```

It throws an InvalidExpressionException because of the Safe Navigation operator. My colleagues aren't experiencing this error and I have confirmed all versions of MVC and Razor dlls in my bin dir are the same.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this is the error you get when this entry (or one similar to it) is omitted from your Web.config. In my case, there was a gulp task that transformed the target Web.config and added this entry. Once I ran that, everything worked.

```
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers>
```